# Is there a benefit to using 2 IMU units on a UAV set at different sensitivities?

Tags: kalman-filter, quadcopter, imu, uav

I noticed that some IMU units are tuned to be sensitive to small changes, other to large changes and some that can be adjusted between different sensitivities. I am familiar with the use of a Kalman filter to normalize readings, but I was wondering if my UAV could benefit from a second IMU where the two are set at high and low sensitivities to get even more accurate and timely information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing two meanings of the word "sensitive".

### Input Sensitivity

If you have an IMU that gives very raw ("twitchy") readings, then you should be able to generate the output of a less input-sensitive IMU by simply computing a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) or using a Kalman filter on the output.

This will produce an effect similar to running a low-pass filter on the output signal; the ability of your filter to reject noise will determine how much accuracy you salvage in this process of subsampling.

### Output Sensitivity

Accelerometers produce analog output, and in many accelerometers you can adjust the number of $mV/g$ that the reading will be.  This is just the scale factor that lets you match the (expected) output of the IMU to the range of your ADC, in order to get the most precision.  So, your intuition is correct -- you could get 2 accelerometers and mix low and high sensitivity to get better precision when reading slight movements.

### Whether It Matters

Ultimately, an IMU that you can buy for less than $50,000 has a limit to its accuracy, and will never be accurate enough for you to use it without other navigational aids -- compasses, GPS units, etc.  Since your vehicle is really only able to react to a certain range of forces, its accelerometers should be tuned to that range.  So, if you have 2 different operating modes that involve 2 different ranges of forces then it might be a good idea to use multiple accelerometers; otherwise, it will produce data that is interesting but not practical (and give you one more source of noise to calibrate).